# Using HTTPS link with php methods (file_get_contents, getimagesize)

Tags: php, https

I get a problem when I try to read some HTTPS url in my website.

If I use "http", there is no problem (with file_get_contents and curl), but when I remplace "http" by "https", these methods don't work.

I get some errors:

```
failed to open stream: operation failed occured

Failed to enable crypto occured

SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

In my browser, all methods work:
https://ssl10.ovh.net/~fyprbqhq/_perso/facebook.myclimb/test.php (Display should show "OK")

In phpinfo() I got:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Version OpenSSL 0.9.8c 05 Sep 2006
```

If you have any ideas.

Thanks for help.

(Ps: get_headers() don't work too with https in my case)

More info:

file_get_contents:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://ssl10.ovh.net/~fyprbqhq/_perso/facebook.myclimb/test.php");
```

Curl:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ssl10.ovh.net/~fyprbqhq/_perso/facebook.myclimb/test.php");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: are you sure that file_get_contents works over http? I have two separate ideas for fopen/curl but they are true only if file_get_contents fails in both cases :) also.. did you try with another https url?

Comment: you could put the line you are using to download the file contents.

Comment: According to what I read on others forums, yeah file_get_contents should works. But in these cases (https), I read that curl is more appropriate. Neverthelesse, I tried to read an google https link, and it's works (with both methods).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%22How+to+diagnose+OpenSSL+errors%22

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the error you received (SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) this is almost certainly caused by the server having a newer version of SSL than your client.

The server is probably using a version >= 1.0.0, while you are using 0.9.8c

Your version of SSL is from 2006. Take a look at the [list of vulnerabilities in OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html) in the last 5 years, as a reason for you to upgrade.

Lots of other people have [reported similar experiences](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3395520&group_id=976&atid=100976)
. Also [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=100976&aid=3395520&group_id=976) and [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-891964-start-0.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.6.x, there's been some changes that effect SSL/TLS negotiation.

> In PHP 5.6, all stream wrappers now verify peer certificates and host names by default when using SSL/TLS.

To work around hosts the have don't have validate ssl / tls sockets, try using this.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
    'capture_session_meta' => TRUE,
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false
]]);

$html = file_get_contents('https://google.com/', FALSE, $ctx);
$meta = stream_context_get_options($ctx)['ssl']['session_meta'];
var_dump($meta);
```

This of course isn't recommended as you are forfeiting the verification of your host.

For me, this came into play while access the flickr api -- api.flickr.com.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php